# Pass column to ST_GeomFromText in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, spatial-query

I would like to apply the st_geomfromtext function on a column called "location" with string values like this:

```
48.125116501359315 13.835729134104216
```

For PostgreSQL this works:

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POINT('||location||')',4326) FROM test;
```

But when I try the same syntax for MariaDB I get the following error:

```
Illegal parameter data type boolean for operation 'st_geometryfromtext'
```

This seems to work (although I get a weird binary result:

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POINT(48.125116501359315 13.835729134104216)',4326);
```

How can I make it work passing the column in MariaDB?

Comment: just a wild guess, but maybe string concatenation works different in mariadb? (not with the or operator). that would explain why the function receives a boolean typed arg

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that in MariaDB concatenation by || is not activated by default. After using this:

```
SET sql_mode=(SELECT CONCAT(@@sql_mode,',PIPES_AS_CONCAT'));
```

it is now working as desired.